# Facebook FacesNot Showing

Tags: facebook, web

I installed the Facebook Like Box plug-in on my TypePad powered blog. It does NOT display the faces of people who Like my Facebook page. Initially it displayed only two members (the dimensions allow for six faces to be displayed). I un-installed it. Two months later I re-installed the plug-in and it displayed the face of only one member (call him "K"). When that member would update his page it would display on the Like Box. However, when new people joined my fan page, the count would increase but their face would not display in the Like Box. The only face that would display was "K". I decided to remove "K" from my members list to see what would happen. The result was the Like Box displayed ZERO faces. I uninstalled the plug in and reinstalled it again, to the same result. At present I'm gaining new members but their faces do not display on the Like Box.

Facebook isn't allowing me to completely paste in the IFrame code but here is most of it:

> iframe
>   src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FLiving-Fit-Healthy-and-Happy%2F342390352362&width=292&height=290&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=true"
>   scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
>   width:292px; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true">

top < then at the bottom /iframe ( <--- I had to type in that in order for Facebook to allow pasting of this code into this question box)

Regardless of the browser - whether it be Firefox or Internet Explorer - the Like Box will not display faces.

I know this is a glitch in the Like Box application, but there has been no technical support from Facebook to deal with this problem. This Like Box is installed on a Business website. The functionality of this app will help me to decide whether to use paid advertising on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

The faces aren't showing when you plug your URL in on the [Like Box Plugin page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) either, so you've got two possibilities: It's a Facebook bug, or it's you.

Let's assume it's you for the moment. First, visit the admin panel of your page and claim a username. You've passed the likes threshold. That alone might fix your problem.

While you're in there, check that you don't have any excessive restrictions on your page.

The only other suggestion is to look at the people who've liked your page. Have any of them set the visibility to "Only Me"? If so, their photos won't show up here.

If you're confident that you've done all that correctly and it still isn't working, [file a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Comment: Thanks. I claimed a user name for my page; I didn't even know this option was available until reading your suggestion. I looked at my restrictions; although my website is family friendly, I had an age restriction 13+ because Facebook itself doesn't allow members of that age. Could that be the reason 0 faces display? (The problem persists, btw).

Comment: The 13+ restriction is the FB default. File a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm signed into Facebook developers page, although I can READ about bug reports but I don't see an option for filing my own report.

Comment: Start typing in the search box. The add a bug report link appears at the bottom of the list of autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and continued help, cpilko. I've been to the Facebook developers support page several times since this problem started. I'm required to sign in as myself instead of my business page; when I type in "Like Box" I'm presented with several trending topics but neither the "create" bug report or subscription options are available to me. So as it stands now I'm not able to even submit a bug report. Hopefully someone from Facebook is reading this thread and can provide assistance in lieu of a bug report.

Comment: Yes, you have to sign in to see the developers page. The "Create a bug" link only shows when you type in the search box: [See here for image](http://i.imgur.com/KrN3C.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, cpilko; unfortunately the "Create a bug" link does not display when I type in search terms including the one shown in your screen shot. I've followed the submit a bug report instructions posted by one of the engineers http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/559/ but something is off regarding my ability to post questions on the developers page. But your advice about claiming my page was helpful. The link looks much more personalized. Now, regarding the problem of faces not displaying in the Like Box, hopefully someone at Facebook is reading this thread and will provide assistance.

Comment: Yes, I've also ran into the Facebook "can't post a bug" bug. The problem resolved itself after a few days, but is annoying. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for offering your help with this issue.